# Как приостанавливать выполнение скрипта в PyQGIS, пока активно окно radiobutton / checkable_combobox и не осуществлен выбор?

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-3.6, radiobutton, qgis

Я работаю во встроенном python-редакторе *QGIS* и в некоторых скриптах хотелось бы использовать `radiobutton` либо `checkable_combobox`, но при запуске таких окон интерпретатор продолжает выполнение скрипта, не давая возможности осуществить выбор и использовать его далее в коде.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, способ останавливать выполнение скрипта, пока активно окно `radiobutton`/`chekable_combobox`, чтобы выбрать нужные пункты/строки, а после закрытия окна продолжить выполнение скрипта.

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        radiobutton = QRadioButton("Australia")
        radiobutton.setChecked(True)
        radiobutton.country = "Australia"
        radiobutton.toggled.connect(self.onClicked)
        layout.addWidget(radiobutton, 0, 0)

        radiobutton = QRadioButton("China")
        radiobutton.country = "China"
        radiobutton.toggled.connect(self.onClicked)
        layout.addWidget(radiobutton, 0, 1)

        radiobutton = QRadioButton("Japan")
        radiobutton.country = "Japan"
        radiobutton.toggled.connect(self.onClicked)
        layout.addWidget(radiobutton, 0, 2)
   def onClicked(self):
       radioButton = self.sender()
       if radioButton.isChecked():
           print("Country is %s" % (radioButton.country))


screen = Window()
screen.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась добавлением checkable_combobox в диалоговое окно (для radiobutton аналогично). Код на примере QgsCheckableComboBox():
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/376901/how-to-put-qgscheckablecombobox-into-standby

```
from qgis.PyQt import QtGui
from qgis.core import *
planet_list = ["Venus", "Earth", "Mars", "Jupiter", "Pluto"]
items = QgsCheckableComboBox()
items.addItems(planet_list)
dlg = QDialog()
layout = QVBoxLayout()
layout.addWidget(items)
dlg.setLayout(layout)
dlg.exec_()
print('\n\n-----------CheckedItems: ', items.checkedItems())
```

Answer (score 0):

Я НЕ работаю во встроенном python-редакторе QGIS, но предложить вам могу следующее:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer, QTime
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):                          # +
#        super().__init__()
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent, Qt.Window)       # +
        
        self.parent = parent                                  # +
        self.country = None                                   # +
        
        layout = QGridLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        radiobutton = QRadioButton("Australia")
#        radiobutton.setChecked(True)                          # -
        radiobutton.country = "Australia"
        radiobutton.toggled.connect(self.onClicked)
        layout.addWidget(radiobutton, 0, 0)

        radiobutton = QRadioButton("China")
        radiobutton.country = "China"
        radiobutton.toggled.connect(self.onClicked)
        layout.addWidget(radiobutton, 0, 1)

        radiobutton = QRadioButton("Japan")
        radiobutton.country = "Japan"
        radiobutton.toggled.connect(self.onClicked)
        layout.addWidget(radiobutton, 0, 2)
        
    def onClicked(self, v):
        radioButton = self.sender()
        if radioButton.isChecked():
            print("Country is %s" % (radioButton.country))
            self.country = f"Country is {radioButton.country}"   # +
            
    def closeEvent(self, event):                                 # +
        self.parent.timer.start()
            

class MyWin(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)

        self.label = QLabel(QTime.currentTime().toString())
        self.button = QPushButton("Выбрать страну")
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.openWindow)
        
        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralWidget)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.button)
        
        self.window = Window(self)
        
        self.timer = QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.changeContent)
        self.timer.start()

    def openWindow(self):
        self.timer.stop()
        self.window.show()
        
    def changeContent(self):
        if self.window.country is None:
            self.timer.stop()
        else:
            self.label.setText(f"{QTime.currentTime().toString()}, {self.window.country}")
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12))
    screen = MyWin()
    screen.resize(600, 400)
    screen.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]